# Passing variable with == in php function

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I am working on a project which is previously coded by someone else before years.

I have come to a code where it is written as

```
$totalTime = $this->getTotalTime($transmissionType == "A", $log);
```

Here before calling this function I find `$transmissionType` and its value is `M`

now the function is defined as

```
public function getTotalTime($AutGears = false){}
```

> Now `$transmissionType = M` means manual

Means $AutGears might be the same and $log might not be used.

But I do not get value M in $AutGears. The reason i find is use of == while passing paremeter in

```
$totalTime = $this->getTotalTime($transmissionType == "A", $log);
```

I haven't seen use of == like this before, but not sure does it really means anything? Or it is a type error?

If it does not mean anything then I will be removing it and my code will run perfect.

> This code is quite old and written in 90s, so I am not sure does this
>   really mean anything.

Comment: `var_dump($transmissionType == "A");`

Comment: Dont know why this question is down voted, I searched it and was not able to find. Even I think it is not duplicated. I just forgot to var_dump it. Anyways, I'll keep it for future reference for someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` returns a boolean value.

```
$isAutomatic = $transmissionType == "A";  // true or false
$totalTime = $this->getTotalTime($isAutomatic, $log);
```

Does this way of writing it make more sense…?

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the quick response. It makes sense now. Will accept your answer.